# i want to build sidebar on my own but the function don't work

Tags: reactjs, sidebar

Sorry for my bad English speak please help me to build a responsive sidebar menu. when i try to build a sidebar menu responsive I reach this type of error : TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function. I haven't an idea where's the error exactly so this is my code of the sidebar menu:

```
import React from 'react';

import {useEffect} from 'react';

import SideNav, { Toggle, Nav, NavItem, NavIcon, NavText } from '@trendmicro/react-sidenav';

import '@trendmicro/react-sidenav/dist/react-sidenav.css';
import {listProducts} from '../actions/productActions';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
    function w3_open() {
  document.getElementByClassName("sidebar").style.width = "100%";
  document.getElementByClassName("sidebar").style.display = "block";
}

function w3_close() {
  document.getElementByClassName("sidebar").style.display = "none";
}

export default  function SideBarMenu() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
        useEffect(()=> {
        dispatch(listProducts);
    }, []) 
    const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
    const {products} = productList;

    console.log(products);
    return (

<div className="wrapper" >
   <div className="section">
            <div className="top_navbar">
                <div className="hamburger">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i className="fa fa-bars" onClick={w3_open(), w3_close()} ><span className="bar-icon"> All products </span></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
             
        </div>
  <div className="sidebar">
          profile image & text
       menu item
    </div>

</div>
  

        
)
    
}
```

and this is the app.js file :

```
import React from 'react';

import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './Pages/HomePage';
import ProductPage from './Pages/productPage';
import SideBarMenu from './components/SideBarMenu';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
  <div className="grid-container" >
        <header className="row" >
          <div>
            <a className="brand" href="/">My shop</a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/cart">Cart</a>
            <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
          </div>
        </header>
        <main>
        <SideBarMenu ></SideBarMenu> 
          <Routes>
           
            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductPage /> }  />
               <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} exact />
          </Routes>
          
        </main>
        <footer className="row center" >All right reserved</footer>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByClassName(...)` doesn't exist in JavaScript. You should use `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` (notice the plural in Elements).

Replace `document.getElementByClassName("sidebar")` with `document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0]`.

### Update

To fix the error that you have right now, I would suggest to use a variable and `useState` Hook to display or hide the sidebar.

Example:

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

const handleSidebar = () => {

    setOpen(!open)

}

return(
    <div className = "wrapper" >
    <div className = "section">
            <div className = "top_navbar">
                <div className = "hamburger">
                    <a href = "#">
                        <i className="fa fa-bars" onClick = {handleSidebar}><span className = "bar-icon"> All products </span></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        { open
        ? <div className = "sidebar">
            profile image & text menu item
          </div>
        : null
        }
    </div>
)
```

Comment: thanks my friend for your help.i'd replace it but it didn't work

Comment: @BorhenKalboussi what error are you getting?

Comment: this time this is the error i had : "index.js:1437 Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
    at i
    at a
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at SideBarMenu (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:903:81)
    at main
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:43259:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:42700:23)
    at App
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:40834:20)

Comment: can i make inside "i tag" an action to be triggered?

Comment: That warning is telling you that you need to include a single function in the `onClick` listener. I would suggest that you use `useState` to hide or display the sidebar instead of using `w3_close` and `w3_open`. (See updated answer above)